# Angular, material side nav and sticky toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm experimenting with material side nav and Angular 6/7. What I want to achieve is shown on the next two images.

The app with collapsed side nav:

[image]

The app with expanded side nav:

[image]

In short:

- a side nav that can open and close with the button.
- a **fixed** toolbar above the content.
- scrollable content.

The basic structure is the following, hinted [here](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview).

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>Sidenav content</mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>Main content, toolbar here</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

A minimal working sample can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qb5sty), at stackblitz.

**My problem:** the toolbar is not sticky and scrolls together with the content when I start scrolling.

**My question:** How can I make the toolbar stick on the top and do not scroll together with the content?

**Note:** The side nav itself is fixed because it has `fixedInViewport="true"`.

Comment: I would add a css class on the `mat-toolbar` element. Then add a position fixed on the css class like `position: fixed`.

As soon as you do this you will notice that your content slides under the toolbar. You can prevent this from happening by wrapping your content with another div and giving that div a `margin-top` with the height of your toolbar.

Comment: I did similar thing, just added a div with class `mat-toolbar-single-row` which is the actual height of the toolbar... Boh... Now I noticed that if I move my HELLO APPLICATION in the rightmost part of the toolbar (by adding a span with `flex: 1 1 auto`) it will slide out of the window when the drawer opens :( I just can believe that there isn't a trivial and supported way to do that VERY simple thing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I edited your slackblitz sample as below.. and also moved the HELLO APPLICATION to right as you said in comment

edited [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvklgg)

done by adding `position-fixed` class with `position: fixed`